# Android Unit Tests aren't getting updated

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing

I have a few unit tests. Some are passing and some are failing. From yesterday, whatever changes I'm making to production code or these test codes, when I run the tests, it's reporting me the old results. I event changed one of my passing tests to this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(1, 2);
```

It's still passing!

I tried restarting Android studio, Invalidating its Caches, updating Android Studio to latest version, even restarting laptop, all with no luck.

Cleaning and rebuilding project sometimes works, but it's heavy and takes a few minutes. And for the next changes I make to code, the same old problem shows itself.

The problem seems to be that it's not making/updating Apk files. Because when I clean project, in the next run it complains about apk file not existing:

```
The APK file ***/app/build/outputs/apk/app-***-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
```

When I rebuild manually, it complains the same about Test apk file:

```
The APK file ***/app/build/outputs/apk/app-***-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk does not exist on disk.
```

**Environment information**
Android Studio 2.1.2
Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
JRE 1.7.0 amd64
JVM OpenJDK 64bit
Gradle 2.10
Gradle plugin 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `Run configuration` of the tests, solved the issue. Maybe it had some invalid configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like your build folder isn't getting refreshed Part of the issue maybe that your using the OpenJDK that isn't supported by Android Studio because it's known to be buggy.

Comment: Yes it is possible. My android studio has always some fatal errors to report to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Here in AS 3.3 and it does the same thing. 
Spent all day trying different things and noticed that when I put in some test text it didn't change. Deleting the run config must have forced it to build... I would think AS is smarter than that :(